# Apply Array Modifier and edit duplications separately

Tags: modifiers

I have used the array modifier and once applied, I would treat the copies as individual objects. For some reason when I try to do the same in this project, it selects all the duplicates along with the original as a single object. Is there something I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect that in your previous project you applied the array modifier before you edited but now you're not?

Comment: What do you mean? I selected the Array modifier and ctrl + A'd it to apply it (otherwise al the other duplicates are just projections of the first, original model).
Here is a screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/EoYP7mi

Comment: That's what I meant.  I was guessing that you hadn't done that.  I suppose you've also done the other two steps from the first answer to the dup question?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Your question was linked to a duplicate question.  If you follow the accepted answer there about separating by loose parts it should solve this.